# Azure allow access to azure portal only through azure vpn

Tags: azure, openvpn, azure-vpn

I have been playing around with azure vpn to have a better understanding of how it works.

I have implemented an azure vpn point to site. Everything works just fine.

But according to my understanding of azure documentation, the azure point to site can be used mainly to access private resource through their private ip or endpoint.

So I was wondering if someone can help me to understand the following point:

rather than accessing azure portal though the open internet, I would like to make the login to azure active directory, exclusively through azure vpn. So if I try to login to the azure portal through my normal wifi, I would like to be blocked, and be guaranteed access only if I am connected to azure vpn.

Is there any solution to this matter?

Thank you very much for your help and any explanation provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional access policy in Azure AD for this. You must define an IP Range and assign it to the policy, restricting access only from this IP

The app that you would restrict access to would be Microsoft Azure Management

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I just activated azure AD premium 2 to have this functionality. But when I go to Az AD => Security => Conditional Access the option `New Policy` is greyed out

Comment: Now its working the policy. just a clarification. Under Cloud apps, I have to select azure vpn right? because I choose azure vpn, but I couldn't create the policy because I need to select the `grant access`

Comment: For cloud app you'd select Microsoft Azure Management, and then you'd select in Conditions>Locations the IP Range of your VPN.

You may try first to restrict access to a specific user before implementing to the entire directory so you can prevent to be locked out.

Comment: There is only one thing that I am not clear about yet. You said that in `condition > locations the IP Range of your VPN` but when I go to location, I am seeing only MFA trusted IPs, exactly like in your screenshot. How this condition knows that the ip range is the one of my VPN if I have only that choice? Thank you much for your help and sorry if I am asking you basic questions

Comment: Sorry to write again. I did implemented all your suggestions, but I am still able to access azure portal even if I am not connected to azure vpn.